# Call to a member function create() on a non-object

Tags: mysql, cakephp, controller

I'm trying to create a new record on a table called `tutors`. I named it that way in order to follow CakePHP conventions.

```
$codigoAlumnoNuevo = $this->Persona->id;
$tipoPersona = $this->request->data('TipoPersona'); # Just grabbing a POSTED value.

switch ($tipoPersona) {
    case '0': # Es Tutor
        $this->Tutor->create();
        $this->Tutor->PersonaId = $codigoAlumnoNuevo;
        $this->Tutor->save();
        die("Saved record");
        break;

    case '1': # Es Alumno
        $this->Tutor->create();
        $this->Tutor->PersonaId = $codigoAlumnoNuevo;
        $this->Tutor->save();
        die("Saved record");
    break;

    case '2': # Es Coordinador de Programa
        $this->Tutor->create();
        $this->Tutor->PersonaId = $codigoAlumnoNuevo;
        $this->Tutor->save();
        die("Saved record");
    break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

When trying to run this code, the following exception fires:

> Call to a member function create() on a non-object

If I try this, I can see that `$this->Tutor` is NULL:

```
var_dump($this->Tutor);
```

But in the same controller, I can call `$this->Persona->create();` just fine; `$this->Persona` is not null. Why is this? Why is Persona available but not Tutor?

Is it a naming thing?

Here's my database model:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `PersonasController` you can only access the `Persona` model by default.

If you want to run creates on the `Tutor` model, you need to add `var $uses = array('Persona','Tutor');` to the beginning of your `PersonasController.php` like so:

```
<?php
class PersonasController extends AppController {
    var $uses = array('Persona','Tutor');

    ....functions.....

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Worth noting that is seems that when using `$uses` I'm also forced to reference other tables I need to use including the previously default "Persona" model table. So it would be: `var $uses = array('Tutor', 'Persona');`

Comment: Good point -- I've updated the answer to reflect this in case someone else reads it and doesn't notice your comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you defined a `hasMany` relationship between `Persona` and `Tutor` in your `Persona` model, you can access the `Tutor` model with `$this->Persona->Tutor->create()` and the `$uses` array from Joseph's answer is not necessary.

Comment: That's good to know. So it's a-lá Ruby on Rails? Can you hook me up with a link to that relevant documentation? Thanks! I think I'd  prefer the RoR way.

Comment: @Serg Please feel free to mark dhofstet's answer as correct instead of my own answer because his way is a much better way of doing it.